# Applying Tab bar theme apart from $base-color?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am applying the following sencha custom theme :

**Sencha Theme Override**

```
$base-color:  #1876fc !default;  //#AB3ABD,
$active-color: darken(#9af3a6,40%) !default;//DD023A
$neutral-color: #e0e0e0;
$base-gradient: 'glossy';

$tabs-bar-gradient:-webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #fc97bb), color-stop(50%, #de0039), color-stop(51%, #a2003d), color-stop(100%, #4e0412));

$global-list-height: 50px;

$back-button-gradient: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #fc97bb), color-stop(50%, #de0039), color-stop(51%, #a2003d), color-stop(100%, #4e0412));
```

**The tab bar gradient doesn't seem to apply. However, if I replace my gradient code with 'recessed', the color on tab bar is applied which is somewhat similar to the base color.**

**I need to set a Custom Tab Bar Gradient . How would I achieve that, keeping in mind that the existing code remains as is?**

**Include Files**

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

@include sencha-panel;
@include sencha-buttons;
@include sencha-sheet;
@include sencha-picker;
@include sencha-tabs;
@include sencha-toolbar;
@include sencha-toolbar-forms;
@include sencha-indexbar;
@include sencha-list;
@include sencha-layout;
@include sencha-carousel;
@include sencha-form;
@include sencha-msgbox;
@include sencha-button-ui('back',#a2003d, 'glossy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$tabs-bar-gradient: color-stops(#fc97bb 0%, #de0039 50%, #a2003d 51%, #4e0412 100%);
```